# Validations attribute

Tags: keycloak

I’m trying to create a new attribute for my user registration in “User Profile”. This new attribute is “Validations” of type “options” (see image). The problem that is giving this error “Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘options’)” is, when accessing the user registry. What am I doing wrong here? Did anyone experience it before?

[image]

Error:
[image]

Please, could someone help me resolve this issue? I need to create an attribute for the user’s registration, which is a list (options), so that the user can choose an item and it will be registered in the database. I am grateful for any help.

I'm new to keycloak. I have read the documentation already and it didn't help. It always gives the error in the image above that I attached.

The version I'm using of keycloak is 22.0.4

Any help would be greatly appreciated.